# Is it safe to screw #14 screws into the bottom of Center Support Beam?

Tags: framing, load-bearing

Making an 8' clothing rack in the basement.  I don't want to weaken the center support beam which is made up of 3 2x10".  Would it be safe to secure the pipe flange with 2 1/2" #14 screws into the bottom of the beam?   Thanks in advance..

[image: Bottom of Center Support Beam]
[image: Pipe with Flange]
[image: 8' pipe for clothing rack]

Comment: I would use #10's, or 12's if its really just for clothes ....

Answer (score 3):

This will be absolutely fine. People put screws into beams all the time. The fibers that run along the beam will barely be broken by this. (Notches out of the beam interrupt the fibers, which makes them another story altogether.)

You might want to predrill with a small (like 1/8") drill bit to make your life a little easier.

Comment: I agree. It should be safe.

Comment: 100% safe no question about it!